# heroku&travis: не отображаются стили sass после деплоя

Tags: github, sass, npm, heroku, travis

Что прописать в конфиге travis.yml, чтобы при деплои на heroku срабатывала команда компиляции scss в css и стили отображались?
есть npm скрипт 
     "sass": "./node_modules/.bin/node-sass public/main.scss public/main.css"

пробовал так, не вышло

```
before_install:
  - export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install -y libappindicator1 fonts-liberation
  - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-    stable_current_amd64.deb
  - sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start

install:
  - npm install
  - npm run sass
```

Comment: css находится в гитигноре. после того,как убрал - заработало. но ведь он должен быть в гитигноре

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем компилировать на сервере? Компилируй локально и делай деплой вместе с компилированным `css`, сделай что-то на подобии `build` скрипта, который будет компилировать тебе `sass` в один css файл, и его же убери из `gitignore`